# Получить атрибут ссылки

Tags: php

При помощи `nodeValue` я получаю текст, всё супер, но мне надо еще и URL получить, который в href находится... Как это сделать? Помогите, пожалуйста. Решения должно быть с foreach как сейчас. Надо что-то добавить?

```
foreach ($node->filter('li:nth-child('1') > a') as $dom) {
          var_dump($dom->nodeValue);  // it's display text from href. Ok good, but i want also get url.     
       }
```

Comment: А что там у Вас в $dom кроме nodeValue находится? Вы пробовали распечатать массив и посмотреть?

Comment: @humster_spb да, я пробовал. Там нету нечего связанного с URL...

Comment: а кусок html из которого вы добываете это все?

Comment: @splash58 спасибо за вопрос, но уже не актуально, ответ уже есть внизу

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У класса `DOMNode` есть `readonly` свойство `attributes`:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domnode.php

```
$attrHref = $aNode->attributes->getNamedItem("href");
if (!is_null($attrHref)) {
  echo $attrHref->nodeValue;
}
```

Comment: спасибо большое, очень спас. Я видел , что там есть свойство attributes но никак вот никак не мог вытaщить url